# Iterate through pandas dataframe, creating new field from existing field based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterator

Here I have some logic for this process:

```
if(group_member_df['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith("gcp") is True):
        group_member_df['group_code'] = (group_member_df['group_email'].str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-'))
        
elif(group_member_df['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith("irm") is True):
        group_member_df['group_code'] = (group_member_df['group_email'].str.extract('^(?:[^-]*\-){6}([^.]*)'))
        
else:
        group_member_df['group_code'] = "null"
```

I have a dataframe that contains multiple columns. The one relevant for this problem is the group_email. From this group email I need to parse out a specific substring from it to get a group_code. I have created two different regex patterns to capture the substring based on the starting. If the email starts with "gcp" I want to follow one specific regex extract and create a group_code in the same row. Or if the email starts with "irm" follow a different regex pattern and do the same. Finally if the email doesn't start with either, just give null  as the group_code.

The first if, is checking if the string starts with "gcp", if that's true, i want to extract from the group_email and create the group_code from this. Same goes with the elif, just with "irm" and different pattern, finally else with null.

How can I modify this so go through each row in the dataframe and run this logic on it?

```
,group_kind,group_id,group_etag,group_email,group_description,group_directMembersCount,group_name,kind,etag,id,email,role,type,status
0,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@ironmountain.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/XprY4N1E2ZREZ95Av98__pbQZXg""",115332437364675590394,astronomer@irm-eap-edp-core-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com,MEMBER,USER,
1,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@ironmountain.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/WDJKr0BpbrpusytGd_HBA_wVzRQ""",102931703871297935722,hema.sundarreddy.contr@ironmountain.com,MEMBER,USER,ACTIVE
2,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@ironmountain.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/1z_mHHk4rwh93nZf55UPPWGjFyc""",111625551155802089398,irm-eap-edp-core-prod@appspot.gserviceaccount.com,MEMBER,USER,
3,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@ironmountain.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/Q7YEC8F_JeB1jKBsNam3u2fiF1o""",107499294203545833692,jarrett.garcia@ironmountain.com,OWNER,USER,ACTIVE
4,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@ironmountain.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/z5Cw_9BaO6gEOiiiX2k9HXfW5uc""",102874697335989237851,shalini.rajamani@ironmountain.com,MEMBER,USER,ACTIVE
5,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@ironmountain.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/G8PLD_6sZpjHCS44h6_9rRXIt0I""",103243562666022054078,suraj.angadi.contr@ironmountain.com,MEMBER,USER,ACTIVE
6,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@ironmountain.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/UU6ouU-RZwaU6rXCFtRmUm0Tjdk""",103099940548030708420,svc.appscripts@ironmountain.com,MANAGER,USER,ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the logic doesn't seem to convoluted, I would consider using a nested `np.where()` for efficiency.

```
group_member_df['group_code'] = np.where(group_member_df.str.startswith("gcp"),
                                         group_member_df.str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-'),
                                         np.where(group_member_df['group_email'].str.startswith("irm"),group_member_df['group_email'].str.extract('^(?:[^-]*\-){6}([^.]*)'),"null"))
```

In a more general approach, but sometimes inefficient, you can use it within pandas' `apply()`. First re-define your logic within a function:

```
def custom_function(row):
     if row['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith("gcp"):
         return row['group_email'].str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-')                    
     elif row['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith("irm"):
         row['group_email'].str.extract('^(?:[^-]*\-){6}([^.]*)')                    
     else:
         return "null"
```

And then pass it to pandas' apply:

```
df['group_code'] = group_member_df.apply(lambda x: custom_function(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried using your options however I keep getting the error: 
ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (992, 992)

Comment: Please share some rows of data

Comment: I've added the data to the post

Comment: Thanks, give me a bit and I will try to review what is not working